# How to modify a rdl in SSRS file with fetchxml for dynamics crm 365

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I am new in dynamics CRM.

I have an rdl file which I extracted from Dynamics CRM 365 and I want to modify this report in SSRS.

Normally, I connect to SQL and am able to edit my reports, but in CRM it is different story.

I downloaded "Microsoft Dynamics 365 Fetch" for my Data Source in visual studio. 
All tutorials talk about how to create a new report with fetchxml and they extract the fetchxml file from CRM with only one entity, but my report consists of more than one entity and I don't know if I can modify the report within the rdl file itself or I should extract the fetchxml file from CRM as well.

If I do need to extract this file from CRM, then how to get the xml file of this specific report with all entities in the report.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you have installed the D365 Fetch component, you should be able to create a new report project in Visual Studio and add your downloaded RDL file as an **existing** file
2. Reports can contain many `datasets` Each dataset represents a FetchXml query
3. You can build your query in the report, but it is recommended to use `Advanced Find` in CRM to build your query (with one or more entities) and then download the FetchXml. This can then be pasted into your rdl's dataset's query text
4. When complete, you can build your reports and upload the compiled report to CRM. I recommend creating a new report so you don't overwrite your existing report until you are sure it works as expected